# A relation on a structure defined as a set? Help with an example from Dalen's Logic and structure

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm not able to understand the folowing example from Dirk van Dalen's logic and structure. What is confusing me is the relation defined on the structure and the predicate $P $.

[image]

We have a set $A=\{0,1 \} $ and a relation defined on $A $ as the set with two elements $\{\langle 0.1 \rangle , \langle 1,0 \rangle \}$. I'm not sure what to make of this relation (being used to relations such as  $<, = $ etc on say $\mathbb N $) . (Maybe the elements should just be thougt of as saying, $0 $ is in relation with $1 $ and $1 $ is in relation with $0 $.)

Then I'm not sure of how the predicate $\phi := P(x,y) $ is defined. (But he speaks of $\langle 0,1 \rangle $ being an element of $P $ and thus it should be thought of as a set?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *structure* [see page 54] $\mathcal{A}$ is "made of" :

- a *domain* $A=\{ 0,1 \}$
- a (binary) *relation* $P^A = \{ ⟨0,1⟩,⟨1,0⟩ \}$ on $A$ as interpretation for the *predicate* symbol $P$. Thus $P^A \subseteq A \times A$. [*Note* : $⟨0,1⟩$ and $⟨1,0⟩$ are the *couples* defining the relation : you can think at $P^A$ as : "___ is brother of :::"].

See page 64 for the *semantics*.

The *structure* is of *type* $⟨2;-;0⟩$ because [see page 55] we have only one *predicate* symbol with *arity* $2$ (thus : $2$), no *function* symbol (thus : $-$) and no *constant* (thus : $0$).

---

You can as well use $\mathbb N$ for a counterexample, considering the "natural" ordering $<$.

Of course :

> $\mathbb N \vDash \forall x \exists y \ (x < y)$ (for each *natural* $n$, it is enough to choose $n+1$);

but :

> > $\mathbb N \nvDash \exists y \forall x \ (x < y)$ (there is **no** *natural* number that is *greater* than any number).

Comment: Okey things are clearing up now. Not exacly sure how this is written correctly but this is about how it is: $\mathbb A \nvDash \exists y \forall xP(x,y)  $ since $ [[\exists y \forall xP(x,y)]]_{\mathbb A } =max \{[[\forall xP(x,y)[a/x]]]_{\mathbb A }...\}  $

and $[[\exists xP(x,y)[a/x]]]_{\mathbb A }=min \{P(x,y)[a/x]... \}=0 $ since for instance $[[P(0,0)]]_{\mathbb A }=0 $ since $\langle 0,0 \rangle \notin P$

Comment: @Alexander - exactly : $min \ max \ne max \ min$.

Answer (score 0):

Here, the author wants to disprove a formula $P$. He wants to do it by exhibiting a model where $P$ is false. A model is a set $A$, plus an interpretation of all relations (a $n$-ary relation is just interpreted as a subset of $A^n$).

Here, he gives $A = \{0,1\}$, and $varphi$ is interpreted as the relation $P$ such that $(0,1) \in P,(1,0)\in P$.

Then this model $\mathfrak A = (A,P)$ is a counter-model of the formula, because it is false in it.

As a true formula have to be true in every model, the considered formula is not true.